# how can I find which day is it by entering a number between 1 and 7 using only one if statement?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

```
public static String GetDayOfWeek(int day){
        String weeks[]={"modnay","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"};
        int day1 = day-1 ;
        for(int i =0; i<weeks.length ; i++){
            if (day1 == weeks[i].lastIndexOf(i)){  // probably here is my mistake 
                return weeks[day1];
            }
       
        }
         return null;
}
```

How can I compare between the input number and the array indexes so I can find which day it is?  Are there any other ways to do it using polymorphism? I thought to create a class for each day and `extends` it to this class but then I will be using more than one if!!

**I have been asked to use one and only one if statement and I can't use more than one if statement or a switch statement.**

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just `return weeks[day-1]` without a for loop or if statement?

Comment: @ThisIsAQuestion I can't do that since I have been asked to use one and only one if statement and I can't use more than one if statement or a switch statement.

Comment: @sayo Why do you need an `if` statement? Can the day be invalid?

Comment: @iota it's an old exam question so it asks to use one if only. that's why I thought I can do it with polymorphism.

Comment: @sayo Does my answer work then?

Comment: @sayo tbh, I sent an email to my professor and still no response that's why I uploaded this question here. if you want I can upload the whole question for better understanding but I feel if I coded it as you suggested it feels too easy for an object-oriented exam and i don't think that's the point of the question sorry

Comment: @iota  my professor just replied "it works" so thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just return the element at the correct index without any looping. You may also want to make the array static. If it is possible for the day to be invalid, you can add an additional check with an `if` statement.

```
public static String getDayOfWeek(int day){
    String[] weeks = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"};
    return day >= 1 && day <= 7 ? weeks[day - 1]: null;
}
```

On a side note, you should always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of your method should be `getDayOfWeek` instead of `GetDayOfWeek`.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String GetDayOfWeek(int day) {
    String weeks[] = {"Modnay", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    if (day > weeks.length || day < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return weeks[day - 1];
}
```